# How to Specify the actvity name in manifest xml file?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Hi everyone i am feeling difficulty in assigning the activity name in manifest xml file.. the file is under com.example.user.pesfinal.activity.AdmissionActivity.java.

```
<activity android:name=".AdmissionActivity" />
```

Would be grateful if someone suggest me how to specify.

Comment: Either user the complete path or relative to the package name.

Comment: form `AndroidMenifest.xml`  tag `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ipartie" >` is base package and as said by @ Rohit5k2 you can use full or relative path

Comment: @ Rohit5k2 I have used complete path but it's giving an error saying that is not assignable to android.app.activity

Comment: @Ritesh Please copy your whole manifest file here

Answer (score 0):

Write -

```
<activity android:name:"com.example.user.pesfinal.activity.AdmissionActivity" />
```

in place of

```
<activity android:name=".AdmissionActivity" />
```